# Same facebook comments on page as on facbeook post?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to have the same comments on a website page as on the facebook post, posted on facebook that has the link from that page?

Now I have comment on the page, but they are different from the comments on the facebook page itself.

Comment: No, that is currently not possible. They are working on a feature called [“comment mirroring”](https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/comments), but that is not publicly available yet AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Was searching all over the place.